# How to check if Dictionary contains letters from string

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

So, i wanted to create some sort of algorithm that will change letters inside string into a int, so lets just say if the string is ABCD the output will be 1234, this will make sure that the same message will be the same every single time, my idea was to create Dictionary that will have char as Key and int as value, then it will loop through the string and inside that loop it wwill loop through everything in the Dictionary, something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < SeedS.Length; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < AlphabetDictionary.Count; j++) {

        //Do something

    }

}
```

and then my idea was to check if what is inside SeedS (with index of i) is equal to what Key is in the dictionary (with index if j) and then just assign value of that location to the output, i tried searching internet for how to do this but i didn't found anything that could help, (i could use array or list but i think that's just lazy and not very good if i can use Dictionary) i used Dictionaries for like 1-2 times and i don't know how to do something like this, i have in mind everything else but i stopped at this point because i don't know what to do now. i would like any help atm because i'm working on this "algorithm" for the past week i guess

PS: i also tried looking at Unity YT tutorial and reading Unity Documentation and i found nothing.

Comment: do you want to check if two messages are the same or the letters at a location are the same?  can you give example of inputs and output -- use cases -- it is not clear at all what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: [`Dictionary.ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey) ?

Comment: Each char already has an int value associated with it, so I don't get what you gain by having a different mapping...

Comment: @insane_developer maybe you don't want the ASCII code but rather a custom int mapping?

Comment: @Hogan i have a procedural generated terrain and the seed must be int so my idea was to convert each letter into number so like A will be 1 B 2 etc etc, and if the input will be AB output will be the value of A then B

Comment: @JakubOravec as insane_developer mentioned every `char` in c# already has an `int` code ... what speaks against using `(int) theChar` ?

Comment: @derHugo well, nothing points to the fact that these custom numbers have any special meaning other than being sequential, so chances are it wouldn't matter what the starting number is.

Comment: @insane_developer yes after the last comment of OP you're probably right ;)

Comment: @OP what is your actual goal with this?

Comment: @derHugo i have procedural generated terrain and i wanted the terrain to be random, so i wanted the player to set own seed but the seed can only be numbers so i came up with idea of converting each letter into string, and also someone helped me and i its working now, just to inform you that its done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answering the actual problem

You say all you actually want is a random seed based on the string input.

It couldn't be easier! If you only need a "seed" which is always the same for same string inputs you could also just use [`string.GetHashCode();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode)

```
var randomSeed = SeedS.GetHashCode();
```

---

#### Answering the title

If you really need a custom map you could use [`Dictionary<Tk, Tv>.TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue) and use two dictionaries to go forth and back

```
private Dictionary<int, char> indexToChar;
private Dictionary<char, int> charToIndex;

public string GetString(IReadonlyList<int> indices)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var id = indices)
    {
        if(indexToChar.TryGetValue(id, out var c)
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

public IReadonlyList<int> GetIndices(string input)
{
    var ids = new List<int>();

    for(var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if(charToIndex.TryGetValue(input[i], out var id)
        {
            ids.Add(id);
        }
    }

    return ids;
}
```

otherwise you could also just use

```
var intValue = (int) someChar;
```

and

```
var charValue = (char) someInt;
```

Comment: Yes get hashcode is what the OP wants -- much faster and quicker than anything with dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```cs
// Create your dictionary here.
var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();

// The string that will be converted.
string str = "Hello";

foreach (char character in str)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(character))
    {
        int value = dictionary[character];

        // Use your value here.
    }
}
```

Dictionaries offer functions to find values by their keys in roughly O(1) time. Iterating over them would take longer and thus would defeat the purpose of using a dictionary.